# Adding an element into a Marisa Trie

Tags: python, spell-checking, trie, spelling

In a spelling error detection task, I use [marisa_tries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/marisa-trie) data structures for my lexicon with Python 3.5.

**Short question**
How to add an element in a `marisa_trie` ?

**Context**
The idea is : if a word is in my lexicon, then it is correct. Now, if it is not in my lexicon, it is probably incorrect. But I computed frequencies of words on the overall document and if a word frequency is high enough, I want to save this word, considering it's frequent enough so probably correct. 
In that case, how to add this new word to my `marisa_trie.Trie` lexicon? (without having to build a new trie every time)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`marisa_trie.Trie` implements an immutable trie, so the answer to your question is: it is not possible.

You might want to try a similar Python package called [`datrie`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datrie) which supports modification and relatively fast queries (PyPI page lists some benchmark against builtin `dict`).